# Localhost wordpress site redirects to public site

Tags: redirect, localhost

On my Mac, I modified the `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Documents/github/gps_cms"
 ServerName gps_cms
 </VirtualHost>
```

That is so I can type gps_cms in URL and invoke the web page on localhost.

However, when I type in:

```
http://gps_cms/wp-admin
```

It redirects to my main site:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php?_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2F
```

And the content on page is this:

> **No Update Required**
>
> *Your WordPress database is already up-to-date!*

Comment: Have you checked your host file on the computer?

Answer (score 3):

WordPress will try to redirect you to the canonical URL for the site, as set in the database during the initial install. But you can override it in the `wp-config.php` file by setting the `WP_HOME` constant:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Blog_address_.28URL.29

If WP is installed in a subdirectory, you might also need to set `WP_SITEURL`.